# Where do I log into local OpenX?

Tags: web, authentication, flash, openx

idiot co-worker went on vacation. Apparently he edits the flash banners through OpenX. I've looked around for 3 hours and can't find where to login to OpenX.

I can't change the flash banner, even by replacing them with other images, or the SWF file with images, it's like a nightmare from hell.

There are the OpenX code files on the server in a folder, OpenX, and plenty of explanations on the internet about how to login to the OpenX website, but i need to login into OPENX on my website. the V.P. is going to flay this guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.website.com/openx/ or http://openx.website.com

Answer (score 0):

You need to login into the Openx server and check the Apache configuration. If you do not have the password you can try with website/openx_install_folder/admin/index.php